# Rename Worksheet Event in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, events

What is the best way to get some VBA code to run when a excel sheet is renamed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one approach. The trick is to trap the events at an application level via a dedicated class. Using the SheetActivate event, store a reference to the active sheet as well as its name. When the sheet is deactiveated (and another activated) compare the name of the sheet reference against the stored string. Here's the class (called CExcelEvents):

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents xl As Application

Private CurrSheet As Worksheet
Private CurrSheetName As String


Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set xl = Excel.Application
    Set CurrSheet = ActiveSheet
    CurrSheetName = CurrSheet.Name
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set xl = Nothing
End Sub



Private Sub xl_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If CurrSheetName <> CurrSheet.Name Then
        Debug.Print "You've renamed the sheet: " & CurrSheetName & " to " & CurrSheet.Name
'       Do something here - rename the sheet to original name?
    End If

    Set CurrSheet = Sh
    CurrSheetName = CurrSheet.Name
End Sub
```

Instantiate this with a global variable using the Workbook open event:

```
Public xlc As CExcelEvents

Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set xlc = New CExcelEvents
End Sub
```

The example above will trigger only when the user selects another worksheet. If you want more granularity, monitor the Sheet Change event as well.

Comment: The only event I can find in Excel 2016 that fires when a sheet is renamed is Application.AfterCalculate. The approach is roughly the same: maintain a mapping of Worksheet objects and their current names, and cross-check all of them during this event.

Answer (score 6):

There apparently is no Event to handle this, even using the Application object. How annoying.

I'd probably try to capture it by storing the startup value of the Worksheet and checking it on as many events as possible - which is admittedly a hack.

The following seemed to work for me, Hope it helps.

In the ThisWorkbook module:

```
Private strWorksheetName As String

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    strWorksheetName = shtMySheet.Name
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Call CheckWorksheetName
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Call CheckWorksheetName
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_WindowDeactivate(ByVal Wn As Window)
    Call CheckWorksheetName
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Call CheckWorksheetName
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Call CheckWorksheetName
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Call CheckWorksheetName
End Sub

Private Sub CheckWorksheetName()
    'If the worksheet has changed name'
    If shtMySheet.Name <> strWorksheetName Then

        DoSomething

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

The only event firing after sheet renamed is `Application.CommandBars_OnUpdate`. Based on this you may create the code which makes fast check if any sheet name changed. Apparently such approach looks clunky and has some overhead due to `OnUpdate` event fires almost on any application's change, anyway that is better than nothing. I noticed that after `Application_SheetSelectionChange` it fires at most about two times per second although, so it should not hang the application.

Here is wrapper class example showing how `Application.CommandBars_OnUpdate` event can help to track some extra worksheet events like add, rename, move and delete.

Create a Class Module, name it `cSheetEvents` and place there the below code:

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Event SheetAdd(ByVal wb As Workbook, ByVal sh As Object)
Public Event SheetRename(ByVal wb As Workbook, ByVal sh As Object, ByVal oldName As String)
Public Event SheetMove(ByVal wb As Workbook, ByVal sh As Object, ByVal oldIndex As Long)
Public Event SheetDelete(ByVal wb As Workbook, ByVal oldName As String, ByVal oldIndex As Long)
Public Event SheetAny()

Private WithEvents app As Application
Private WithEvents appCmdBars As CommandBars
Private skipCheck As Boolean
Private sheetData As Object

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    
    Set app = Application
    Set appCmdBars = Application.CommandBars
    Set sheetData = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim wb As Workbook
    For Each wb In app.Workbooks
        Dim sh As Object
        For Each sh In wb.sheets
            sheetData(sh) = Array(sh.Name, sh.index, wb)
        Next
    Next
    
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    
    Set sheetData = Nothing
    
End Sub

Private Sub app_NewWorkbook(ByVal wb As Workbook)
    
    Dim sh As Object
    For Each sh In wb.sheets
        sheetData(sh) = Array(sh.Name, sh.index, wb)
    Next
    
End Sub

Private Sub app_WorkbookOpen(ByVal wb As Workbook)
    
    Dim sh As Object
    For Each sh In wb.sheets
        sheetData(sh) = Array(sh.Name, sh.index, wb)
    Next
    
End Sub

Private Sub app_WorkbookNewSheet(ByVal wb As Workbook, ByVal sh As Object)
    
    sheetData(sh) = Array(sh.Name, sh.index, wb)
    RaiseEvent SheetAdd(wb, sh)
    RaiseEvent SheetAny
    skipCheck = True
    
End Sub

Private Sub app_SheetChange(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    
    skipCheck = True
    
End Sub

Private Sub appCmdBars_OnUpdate()
    
    If skipCheck Then
        skipCheck = False
    Else
        Dim anyEvt As Boolean
        Dim wb As Workbook
        For Each wb In app.Workbooks
            Dim sh As Object
            For Each sh In wb.sheets
                If Not sheetData.exists(sh) Then
                    sheetData(sh) = Array(sh.Name, sh.index, wb)
                    RaiseEvent SheetAdd(wb, sh)
                    anyEvt = True
                End If
            Next
        Next
        On Error Resume Next
        For Each sh In sheetData
            Set wb = sheetData(sh)(2)
            If wb.Name = "" Then
                sheetData.Remove sh
                Set sh = Nothing
                Set wb = Nothing
            Else
                Dim oldName As String
                oldName = sheetData(sh)(0)
                Dim oldIndex As Long
                oldIndex = sheetData(sh)(1)
                If sh.Name = "" Then
                    sheetData.Remove sh
                    Set sh = Nothing
                    RaiseEvent SheetDelete(wb, oldName, oldIndex)
                    anyEvt = True
                Else
                    If sh.Name <> oldName Then
                        sheetData(sh) = Array(sh.Name, sh.index, wb)
                        RaiseEvent SheetRename(wb, sh, oldName)
                        anyEvt = True
                    ElseIf sh.index <> oldIndex Then
                        sheetData(sh) = Array(sh.Name, sh.index, wb)
                        RaiseEvent SheetMove(wb, sh, oldIndex)
                        anyEvt = True
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
        If anyEvt Then
            RaiseEvent SheetAny
        End If
    End If
    
End Sub
```

In the example some unnecessary `OnUpdate` events right after `Application_SheetChange` skipped to reduce overhead by adding flag variable. You may try to skip other unnecessary events. Note, that e. g. `Application_SheetSelectionChange` event fires when a user renames the sheet by typing and after that clicks on whatever (not selected) cell on the sheet, and `Application_SheetCalculate` event fires when the sheet is renamed and there are volatile formulas exist somewhere.

For testing you may use any object module, let's say, `ThisWorkbook` Module, place the below code in it:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents sheetEvents As cSheetEvents

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    
    Set sheetEvents = New cSheetEvents
    
End Sub

Private Sub sheetEvents_SheetAdd(ByVal wb As Workbook, ByVal sh As Object)
    
    MsgBox _
        "Sheet added" & vbCrLf & _
        Now & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "Workbook: " & wb.Name & vbCrLf & _
        "Name: " & sh.Name
    
End Sub

Private Sub sheetEvents_SheetRename(ByVal wb As Workbook, ByVal sh As Object, ByVal oldName As String)
    
    MsgBox _
        "Sheet renamed" & vbCrLf & _
        Now & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "Workbook: " & wb.Name & vbCrLf & _
        "Old name: " & oldName & vbCrLf & _
        "New name: " & sh.Name
    
End Sub

Private Sub sheetEvents_SheetMove(ByVal wb As Workbook, ByVal sh As Object, ByVal oldIndex As Long)
    
    MsgBox _
        "Sheet renamed" & vbCrLf & _
        Now & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "Workbook: " & wb.Name & vbCrLf & _
        "Name: " & sh.Name & vbCrLf & _
        "Old index: " & oldIndex & vbCrLf & _
        "New index: " & sh.Index
    
End Sub

Private Sub sheetEvents_SheetDelete(ByVal wb As Workbook, ByVal oldName As String, ByVal oldIndex As Long)
    
    MsgBox _
        "Sheet deleted" & vbCrLf & _
        Now & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "Workbook: " & wb.Name & vbCrLf & _
        "Name: " & oldName & vbCrLf & _
        "Index: " & oldIndex
    
End Sub
```

Save the workbook, and reopen it, after that each `SheetRename` and `SheetDelete` event will be alerted.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but I've recently begun to use Excel's `CELL("filename")` function which returns details about both file and sheet names.

We can parse the sheet name, using this well-known formula:

> =MID(CELL(""filename"", A1),FIND(""]"",CELL(""filename""," A1))+1,255)"

By writing this function to a hidden worksheet, and then monitoring the `_Calculate` event on that sheet, we can catch any change to the worksheet name.

I had to resort to this method because I needed to share some VBA code with a client, which gave him the possibility to change certain worksheet names programmatically as well as by typing onto the tab. This method captures a sheet name changed event even if it was made in code.

In the skeleton code below, I've just captured the name change for the active worksheet but there's nothing to stop you adding a target worksheet list and adjusting the handling code accordingly.

The code below is in the Workbook code-behind:

```
Option Explicit
Private mSheetNamesWS As Worksheet
Private mOldSheetName As String

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    'Find or create the hidden worksheet
    'containing the sheet reference.
    On Error Resume Next
    Set mSheetNamesWS = Me.Worksheets("SheetNames")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If mSheetNamesWS Is Nothing Then

        'Disable events so that the _calculate event
        'isn't thrown.
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        Set mSheetNamesWS = Me.Worksheets.Add
        With mSheetNamesWS
            .Name = "SheetNames"
            .Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
        End With

        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If

    'Update the sheet reference.
    If TypeOf ActiveSheet Is Worksheet Then
        UpdateCellFormula
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    'Active sheet has changed so update the reference.
    If TypeOf ActiveSheet Is Worksheet Then
        UpdateCellFormula
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateCellFormula()
    Dim cellRef As String

    'Sense check.
    If mSheetNamesWS Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    'The CELL function returns details about
    'the file and sheet name of any
    'specified range.
    'By adding a formula that extracts the
    'sheet name portion from the CELL function,
    'we can listen for any changes
    'of that value in the _calculate event method.

    'Disable events to avoid a spurious
    '_calculate event.
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    cellRef = ActiveSheet.Name & "!A1"
    With mSheetNamesWS.Range("A1")
        .Formula = _
            "=MID(CELL(""filename""," & _
            cellRef & _
            "),FIND(""]"",CELL(""filename""," & _
            cellRef & _
            "))+1,255)"
        mOldSheetName = .Value
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)

    'Disregard any sheet that isn't our reference sheet.
    If Not Sh Is mSheetNamesWS Then Exit Sub

    'The reference sheet has recalculated.
    'It means the value of the cell containing
    'the current sheet name has changed.
    'Ergo we have a sheet name change.

    'Handle the event here ...
    MsgBox "You can't change the name of this sheet!"
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ActiveSheet.Name = mOldSheetName
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm eagerly awaiting an answer to this because I haven't figured it out after much searching.  There is no rename event on a worksheet that I have found, so you are forced to have an alternative approach.

The best one I have seen (which is *awful*) is to prohibit rename on the sheets by making them read-only or invisible, and then provide your own toolbar or button that does the rename.  Very ugly and users hate it.

I have also seen applications that disable the rename menu item in the office toolbar, but that doesn't prevent double-clicking the tab and renaming there.  Also very ugly and users hate it.

Good luck, I hope someone comes up with a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I acheived it.

Created two Named Ranges the first "SheetName" on "A1" or wherever you would like, then add the formula  =TEXTAFTER(CELL("filename",A1),"]")  to the cell.  This gets the sheet name.   Then the other named range is called  "SheetNamePrevVal"  tracks the previous value, I put this on "A2" for my test.

On the sheet that you want the sheet name checked add the below code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If CStr(Range("SheetName").Value) <> CStr(Range("SheetNamePrevVal").Value) Then
        Call MyCode
        Range("SheetNamePrevVal").Value = Range("SheetName").Value
    End If
End Sub
```