# How to know if a sheet is renamed in Excel

Tags: excel, vsto

I have a plugin for Excel ( VSTO) that needs to know when a user renames a Sheet
Is there any event that would tell me this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no worksheet name change event or anything similar. What you could do is save the name of the worksheet and then compare the name to the saved name in some other event, for example worksheet deactivate (and / or other events). See a similar question here:
[Rename Worksheet Event in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939919/rename-worksheet-event-in-excel)