# Automatically update a list when worksheet names change

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to update a list in a spreadsheet with all of the worksheets that contain a certain set of characters.

I have a button that I press to update the list, but I want to make this happen whenever a tab name is changed. I have seen a lot of comments about Worksheet_change(ByVal Target as String) and I am hoping to use something like this.

Comment: Will you always know what the sheet name is, before it's changed?  Also, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939919/rename-worksheet-event-in-excel)

Comment: May be useful - you could use a formula to return the sheet names of a saved workbook.  You just need to reference a cell (any cell) on the sheet:  `=MID(CELL("filename",'Sheet1'!$A$1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",'Sheet1'!$A$1))+1,LEN(CELL("filename",'Sheet1'!$A$1)))`

Comment: No. I will not know the sheet name. This is a case of numbered tabs with a set of prefixes. For example, a sheet name may be ADJB-001 or AJB-004. however, it may be necessary to change ADJB-001 to AJB-001.