# Tracking workbook and worksheet renames

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-dna

Is there any way to get an event when a workbook or a worksheet is renamed in an Excel-DNA based addin? Apparently, the Application object doesn't expose these events directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API way, but there are quite a few workarounds.

Maybe this will help:

[Rename Worksheet Event in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939919/rename-worksheet-event-in-excel)